# a/b testing a major html/css redesign

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ab-testing

At my company we are redesiging our e-commerce website. HTML and CSS is re-written from the ground up to make the website responsive / mobile friendly.

Since it concerns one of our biggest websites which is responsible for generating of over 80% of our revenue it is very important that nothing goes "wrong".

Our application is running on a LAMP stack.

**What are the best practices for testing a major redesign?**

Some issues i am thinking of:

- When a/b testing a whole design (if possible) i guess you definitaly
  dont want Google to come by and index youre new design (since its
  still in test phase). How to handle this?
- Should you redirect a percentage of the users to a new url (or
  perhaps subdomain)? Or is it better to serve the new content from the
  existing indexed urls based on session?
- How to compare statistics from a Google Analytics point of view?
  How to hint Google about a new design? Should i e.g.
  create a new UA code?

Comment: Well for starters if you're testing a major design change, you don't want to be testing on your **live site**. It should have been tested in a staging/sandbox environment before going live.

Comment: Of course we are taking care of that. But it is e.g. very important that our conversion rate stays the same since we cant afford a major fallback. So before we launch the whole redesign it would be nice if we can benchmark this (and other) stuff a little bit.

Comment: Your business model is not well insulated from your customers 80% in one bucket. When you are ready to go live you need to try to identity if the Web request is from an 80%, if so redirect them to current system. When you've had a period of running the new stuff successfully dealing with new customers and the other 20% for a while, you need to migrate the 80% onto this new version. From experience users freak out if you change a menu option or add a new icon to their desktop, you really need to hold their hand when adding new columns to screens and reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution might be to set a cookie only for customers who enter the website via the homepage. Doing so, you're excluding adwords traffic and returning visitors, who might be expecting an other webdesign, serve them the original website and leave their experience untouched.

Start the test with home traffic only, set cookie and redirect a percentage to a subdomain. Measure conversion rate by a dimension in Google analytics, within same analytics account. Set a 'disallow subdomain' in your robots.txt to exclude the subdomain from crawling by SE's.

Comment: This was what i was looking for. Nice one on the homepage cookie only btw! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Marc, You’re mixing a few different concerns here:

1. Instrumentation. If you changes can be expressed via HTML/CSS/JavaScript only, i.e. optimizational in nature, you may be able to instrument using tols like [VWO](http://vwo.com) or [Optimizely](http://optimizely.com). If there are server side changes too, then a tool like [Sitespect](http://sitespect.com) (any server stack) or [Variant](http://getvariant.com) (Java only) might be in order. The advantange of using a commecial product is that they provide a number of important features out of the box, e.g. collecting experiment data, experience stability (returning user sees the same experience), etc. You may be able to instrument on your own, but unless you’re looking at a handful of pages, that typically is hard, particularly if you want to do it outside of the app, via the DevOps mechanisms.
2. SEO. If you get your instrumentation right, this shouldn’t be an issue. Public URIs should not differ for the control and variant of the same resource.
3. Traffic routing. Another reason to consider a commercial tool. They factor that out of your app and let you set percentages. Some tools, like Variant, will allow you to write custom targeters, e.g. “value” users always see control.